# apply rug frings on svg carpet

Tags: svg, path, svg-animate

I have a svg carpet need to apply rug fringes on carpet.

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  
  

  <!-- Points -->
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="red"/>

</svg>
```

consider this circle as a carpet and i want to apply rug as like border. how we can scale path dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. Do you mean you want to add a fringe-like effect to the edge of the circle?

Like this?

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  
  <!-- Points -->
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="red"
          stroke="black" stroke-width="6" stroke-dasharray="1 2"/>

</svg>
```

Comment: it should be image, we have different kind of rug,